# Change required property of a field in Microsoft Access based on other field with Yes/No type

Tags: ms-access

I'm using Microsoft Access 2013. As mentioned in the title, I want to change the "Required" property of one field (A) based on the field (B) with Yes/No type.
For example, if the B returns "No", so the "Required" of A turns to "No".
Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: Much easier to be handled in Code, than the table definition. Just on the side note, no this is not possible with a table data macros.

Comment: So sir, do you have any suggestion for Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to remove the Required constraint on the Field A. Then use the Form Before Update event to check for the constraint.

```
Private Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.FieldNameB = -1 Then
        If Len(Me.FieldNameA & "") = 0 
            MsgBox "This field cannot be left empty.", vbInformation, "Required information."
            Cancel = True
        End If 
    End If 
End Sub
```

This will not allow the Form to be closed, if the `FieldB` is selected and no input was entered in `FieldA`.